# How to host in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Looking for some advice on the best and cheapest way to host in azure and I’ve never used it before so I’m finding it fairly confusing if I’m honest. But here’s where I’m at...

I have a Vue.js front-end which calls an azure function back end (API in .net core using VS) which is connected to mysql workbench running as a windows service currently, which ultimately returns all data back to my front end.

I set up a free trial tonight, I’ve created a resource group and set up an azure function and pushed my API up to it. I then created an azure for mysql instance and managed to connect my DB up (again from mysql workbench running as a windows service) to my azure mysql instance and connected this also with credentials to my API.

I need to now host the Vue.js app and connect this to my azure function but how are the endpoints exposed ?

Also, I have registered a domain and I’d assume I’d have to connect this to the Vue.js app once it’s hosted but any tips ?

I need to keep this as cheap as possible.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started?tabs=vanilla-javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the cheapest ways to host your website is using a Azure blob storage. You can set it up for static websites, I've done this a couple of times for Angular applications. [blob documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)

As for exposing your API. Make sure that your Azure function has a http trigger and the correct authorization level. You can obtain an url as prescribed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api).

Please let me know if you need anything else :).

Comment: But would the Vue.js side of things be classed as static ? It’s content driven from the DB via the API?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Vue.js. But a static website doesn't mean it is actually 'static' like html & css only. So as long as all your Vue logic is client-side it's not a problem at all. If you need a back-end server for server side rendering for example, serving from a blob container is not a option!

Comment: Blob storage works well for me! I ended up doing this. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Please make sure you accept my anwser as  the solution. This helps me and the community :). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I will do thank you! Any idea how I can pull out keys (such as endpoints etc so I can have different environments with locahost endpoints locally and live endpoints live) into azure and reference them in the app itself? I was thinking keyvault, but it looks like there's costs associated with literally everything.

Comment: I think you're looking for Arm templates. You can deploy all your Azure resources, including environment specific settings, with them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview. Yes most of the services have costs associated with them, but luckily it's pay-as-you-go!